# Unable to generate temporary class in Windows 2008 R2 64 bit for C# app

Tags: c#, class, 64-bit, temporary

I have no clue whats going on here. My c# (VS2008) app runs fine in 32 bit OS but when i run the same in Windows 2008 R2 64bit i am getting following error:

Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0008: Unexpected error reading metadata from file 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\xxxx\7.0.1001.0__5b72a65e64576834\xxxx.dll' -- 'Bad Key. '

Looked through some articles, which says if there is no sufficient permissions to temp folder this error will popup. And i have given permissions to temp folder "C:\windows\temp" and user temp folder ("C:\users\\appdata\local\temp") but no luck. I have a webservice proxy class in this assembly, which requires XML serialization and i guess uses temp folder to create serialized assembly at run time, where it is throwing this error.

Any inputs much appreciated. BTW i found that error (unable to generate.....) in event viewer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of fundamental things wrong in your question.  This is a compile time error, not a runtime error.  Note CS0008 in the message, documented as:

*A DLL was successfully opened for retrieving metadata but is corrupted, such that data could not be read from it. For more information, see /reference (Import Metadata) (C# Compiler Options).*

Next thing that's wrong is that this assembly clearly comes from the GAC.  The compiler should *never* reference an assembly from the GAC, reference assemblies have to be copies stored in a relevant directory.  Like c:\windows\microsoft.net\etc for the .NET framework assemblies.

Whatever you did to get this error clearly voided the warranty.  I cannot reverse-engineer what you did from your question, obfuscating the assembly name certainly did not help.

Comment: You can safely assume the assembly name is something proprietary if it appears to be obfuscated intentionally.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am running the app from the installer and the assembly is not .net system assembly. I tried compiling this project in 64 bit and it compiles fine without errors in VS 2008 also runs fine. The problem is if i use installer to install this solution and run i am getting the above specified error.

Comment: An update -- when i build the project with target platform as x64, everything works fine. Are we suppose to build target as x64 for 64 bit OS?

Comment: OK, i found the cause to the problem. We added InternalsVisibleTo attribute to assembly class which is causing this issue. Not sure why that will cause issue. May be its a bug in 64 bit OS.